# Making bot delete everything in a channel except for a command and response [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

Edited: I finally made the code working but only for one channel. Is there a way to make it 2 channels? Tried doing 'or' but it doesn't work. It only accepts one channel or sometimes it ignores everything.

Ex. Delete every user message in general and test except for !ask or !question in general and !test in test

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.guild:
        return
    if not message.channel.name == 'general':
        return
    if message.channel.name == 'general' and message.content != '!ask' or '!question':
        if message.author.bot:
            pass
        else:
            await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check wether if the [message author is a bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20bot#discord.Member.bot) (response to a command) or if the message contains a [command name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command.name) by exploring [every commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands):

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, ctx):
    if not message.guild:
       return
    for command in self.client.commands:
        if command.name in message or message.author.bot:
            return
    await message.delete()
```

To make it work on specific channels, you have multiple choices:

- Using a dictionnary (not very efficient if you have many channels/servers to handle):

  ```py
  bot_channels = {}

  @commands.command()
  async def bot_channel(self, ctx):
      try:
          temp = bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]
      except:
          bot_channels[ctx.guild.id] = [ctx.channel.id]
          print(f"Set {ctx.channel} as a bot channel")
      else:
          if ctx.channel.id in bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]:
              bot_channels[ctx.guild.id].pop(ctx.channel.id)
              print(f"{ctx.channel} is no longer a bot channel")
          else:
              bot_channels[ctx.guild.id].append(ctx.channel.id)
              print(f"Set {ctx.channel} as a bot channel")

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, ctx):
      try:
          temp = bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]
      except:
          return
      else:
          if not message.guild:
              return
          for command in self.client.commands:
              if (command.name in message or message.author.bot) and message.channel.id in bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]:
                  return
          await message.delete()
  ```
- Using the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and json files (more efficient with a moderate amount of data):
  The json file

  ```
  {}
  ```

  Your python code

  ```py
  from json import loads, dumps

  @commands.command()
  async def bot_channel(self, ctx):
      with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
          data = file.read()
          bot_channels = loads(data)
      try:
          temp = bot_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)]
      except:
          bot_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)] = [ctx.channel.id]
          print(f"Set {ctx.channel} as a bot channel")
      else:
          if ctx.channel.id in bot_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)]:
              bot_channels[ctx.guild.id].pop(ctx.channel.id)
              print(f"{ctx.channel} is no longer a bot channel"
          else:
              bot_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)].append(ctx.channel.id)
              print(f"Set {ctx.channel} as a bot channel")
      with open("filename.json", "w") as file:
          bot_channels = file.write(dumps(bot_channels))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
            data = file.read()
            bot_channels = loads(data)
        try:
            temp = bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]
        except:
            return
        else:
            if not message.guild:
                return
            for command in self.client.commands:
                if (command.name in message or message.author.bot) and message.channel.id in bot_channels[ctx.guild.id]:
                    return
            await message.delete()
  ```
- If you have a lot of data, to make it efficient, you'll have to use a database (In this case, I can't help you)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is whenever a user chat in that channel it will delete it except for the command and the bot's reply. Also the code that I did it deletes everything even if it's not in the general channel..

Comment: I edited my post! It's working but only for one channel. Is there a way to do it with 2 channels? The thing is we want those channels to be a non chat channels and only 1 command will work in each channel.

Comment: Yes there is a way, you can look at the code I've added to my answer

Comment: Thank you for answering me! I tried it with json but nothing happens when I entered the code and whenever I put it in a cog it gives me an error. Nothing is being dumped in the json too.

Comment: I forgot to put `self` in the functions first variables. Also, I didn't write `as file` in `with open("filename.json", "r")` and `with open("filename.json", "w")`. Is the path to your file correct / have you replaced `filename.json` with your filename ?

Comment: Yup! I put the directory/filename.json on it but it doesn't seem to do something and if it's in a cog, it gives an error for my reload, load and unload cogs command.

Comment: If your main program (which runs the bot) is outside the cog, and your file is in a cogs folder, you'll have to put foldername/filename.json as the path.

Comment: Yes I did that but nothing happened. I copied the file directory of the json and put it there.

Comment: `print(f"{ctx.channel} is no longer a bot channel"` l.11: I forgot a bracket at the end :(